# Read json through streams

Tags: java, stream, java-stream

I have the below code and I'm expecting the **myList** to have the following. The code works I just wanted to do it in a single stream expression.

`my
test
data
preview
Data
env
param`

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
    myList.add("my");
    myList.add("test");
    myList.add("data");

    JsonDataResp json = getJsonResponse(); // This give the obj of the below JSON

    List<InnerArr> innerArrs = json.getInnerArr();

    for(InnerArr arr: innerArrs){
        if(myList.contains(arr.getCurrent())){
            myList.add(arr.getNew());
        }
    }
    myList.addAll(json.getStringToSplit().split("\\s"));
```

My Json response looks like the below

`{
  "stringToSplit": "env param",
  "innerArr": [
    {
      "current": "test",
      "new": "preview"
    },
    {
      "current": "string",
      "new": "Data"
    },
     {
      "current": "archive",
      "new": "dump"
    }
  ]
}`

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the for loop with this:

```
innerArrs.stream().filter(x -> myList.contains(x.getCurrent())).forEach(x -> {
    myList.add(x.getNew());
});
```

Comment: I need to include the splitting to this.. can I do that

Comment: I don't see how you can stream 2 collections of different types simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work with only streams for whatever reason, the following will work:

```
Stream.concat(innerArrs.stream()
                        .filter(arr -> myList.contains(arr.getCurrent()))
                        .map(InnerArr::getNew),
                Stream.of(json.getStringToSplit().split("\\s"))
).forEach(myList::add);
```